# Calculate the conditional variance-covariance matrix to optimal hedge ratio bekk

Tags: optimal-hedge-ratio

I estimated an MGARCH-BEKK model (using the R package `BEKK`, i.e. **B**aba, **E**ngle, **K**raft and **K**roner; see [Engle and Kroner (1995)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3532933)) on time series of spot and futures prices. The estimated parameters are:

```
  =====================================================
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(> | t| )
  -----------------------------------------------------
  mu1.DLog_Base  -0.002    0.001    -1.498     0.134   
  mu2.DLog_B3    0.0003    0.001     0.282     0.778   
  A011           0.004     0.003     1.047     0.295   
  A021           0.0004                                
  A022           0.013     0.001    14.475       0     
  A11            0.008     0.027     0.314     0.754   
  A21            -0.096    0.089    -1.077     0.282   
  A12            -0.052    0.088    -0.588     0.557   
  A22            0.661     0.122     5.395    0.00000  
  B11            0.967     0.010    96.058       0     
  B21            0.124                                 
  B12            0.073     0.123     0.596     0.551   
  B22            0.011     0.185     0.058     0.953   
  -----------------------------------------------------
```

I don't now to calculate the conditional variance and covariance matrix.

$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \sigma_{ss} & \sigma_{sf} \\
   \sigma_{fs} & \sigma_{ff} \\
  \end{array} } \right] = 
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   c_{11} & 0 \\
   c_{21} & c_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   c_{11} & 0 \\
   c_{21} & c_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right] +
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{11} & 0 \\
   0 & a_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \epsilon_{s,t-1}^2 & \epsilon_{s,t-1}\epsilon_{f,t-1} \\
   \epsilon_{fs,t-1}\epsilon_{s,t-1} & \epsilon_{f,t-1}^2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{11} & 0 \\
   0 & a_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

$$
+ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   b_{11} & 0 \\
   0 & b_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \sigma_{ss,t-1} & \sigma_{sf,t-1} \\
   \sigma_{fs,t-1} & \sigma_{ff,t-1} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   b_{11} & 0 \\
   0 & b_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

My conditional variance and covariance matrix:

$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \sigma_{ss} & \sigma_{sf} \\
   \sigma_{fs} & \sigma_{ff} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right] = $$
$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.004 & 0 \\
   0.0004 & 0.013 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.004 & 0 \\
   0.0004 & 0.013 \\
  \end{array} } \right] +
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.008 & 0 \\
   0 & 0.661 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \epsilon_{s,t-1}^2 & \epsilon_{s,t-1}\epsilon_{f,t-1} \\
   \epsilon_{fs,t-1}\epsilon_{s,t-1} & \epsilon_{f,t-1}^2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.008 & 0 \\
   0 & 0.661 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

$$
+ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.967 & 0 \\
   0 & 0.011 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \sigma_{ss,t-1} & \sigma_{sf,t-1} \\
   \sigma_{fs,t-1} & \sigma_{ff,t-1} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.967 & 0 \\
   0 & 0.011 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

To calculate the optimal hedge ratio `BEKK`:

$$h_t = \frac{cov \left( \Delta S_t, \Delta f_t \mid \Omega_{t-1} \right) }{var \left( \Delta f_t \mid \Omega_{t-1} \right)}$$

$\Delta S_t$, $\Delta f_t$ is the return price spot and future, and $\Omega_{t-1}$ is conditional variance and covariance matrix.

Comment: Could you please restate your Question in english/Por favor reformular en ingles!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - It is Portuguese rather than Spanish.  The introductory line is translated by Google Translate as "I have the result of the coefficients of the BEKK model:" and the final line as "How to create the optimal ratio and effectiveness of these coefficients?"

Comment: Sorry. I need to calculate the Hedge Efficiency and Optimal Hedge Ratio for the future Market.

Comment: @Everton Toledo: Can you please edit that into the original question?

Comment: Yes, I edit, thank you Kjetil.

Comment: If your only question is 'How do I _____ in R?', then it's most likely off topic here. You may have a statistical question, but you need to clarify what it is, if so. Alternatively, this may be a quantitative finance question, in which case we could possibly migrate it to the [quant.SE] SE site, but it presumably needs to be clarified & sufficient context provided for that site as well.

Comment: I will migrate this to the [quant.SE] SE site, where you should be able to get some help. Please remain engaged with this Q: follow it there to create an account on that site, respond to comments, & edit to clarify & provide more info as needed.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I try to calculate in R, the package MTS, in function BEKK11. Do you now other solution in R? I've price returns spot and future soybean. Sorry my English, I'm from Brazil....

Comment: Do you agree that $cov(\Delta S_t,\Delta f_t)$ is the same as $\sigma_{sf}$ and $var(\Delta f_t)$ is the same as $\sigma_{ff}$? Or am I wrong about that ?

Comment: Yes, others dissertation explain the equation: ht = hsf,t/hff,t. So, I don't now to calculate.... For example, in the linear regression, the optmial hedge ratio is the β and the calculate efficienty is R2. I want to compare the static model with the dynamic one

Comment: The "hedge efficiency" is the percentage reduction in variance due to hedging. If the variance of $\Delta S_t$ (the unhedged price changes) is 20 and the variance of $\Delta S_t - h_t*\Delta f_t$ is 15 then the "hedge efficiency" is (20-15)/20 = 25% efficiency. In the case of regression hedging this is also $R^2$. The efficency can go up to 100% (or 1.0) in the best case.

Comment: ok. but the Optimal Hedge Ratio model BEKK is my problem .

Comment: Model BEKK definition:
ε_,t-1 is an error-lagged vector of order 1 and C, A, B are square matrices; and C is lower triangular, guaranteed the σ_t-1 positive covariance matrix.
hss is variance of the spot price log, hff is the variance of the future price log, hsf is covariance. c11,c21,c22 , are the constant coefficients of the model. a11,a22 only the parameters of the spot price log. b11,b22 only the parameters of the future price log. ε_s,t-1^2 is variance  first diff the spot price log. ε_f,t-1^2 is variance  first diff the future price log. ε_s,t-1 ε_f,t-1 is covariance .

Comment: Please stop making duplicates.

Comment: Sorry @Bob Jansen. Tks